# How can I pass a string to pexpect spawn?

Tags: python, pexpect

I want to ssh to another node on my network as part of a larger python script, I am using pexpect which works when I do something like this:

```
session=spawn('ssh root@172.16.210.254')
```

I want to replace the address with a variable so I can cycle through addresses in a list however when I try:

```
address = "172.16.210.253"

session=spawn('ssh root@'address)
```

It doesn't work as using address in this way is invalid syntax. What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`session=spawn('ssh root@' + address)`  to concatenate the strings

Comment: Or, more generally, `'ssh root@{}'.format(address)`, which allows you to insert a variable anywhere in a string, instead of just at the end. See [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more details.